# Different Javascript behaviour in different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, events

I'm doing a eCommerce website, but dealing Javascript is killing me.

For example, for the following page, http://nordschleife.metaforix.net/118/118/index.php/sony.html

It works as intended in Google Chrome, but not in IE or Firefox. For instance, clicking the up or down arrow for products that are down the page (e.g., tenth product) will cause the page to go up.

I've already used event.preventDefault(); but it doesn't work for IE and Firefox. The JS is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     $('#upImg_<?php echo $_product->getId();?>').live("click", function() {
                                var textbox = document.getElementById('qty_<?php echo $_product->getId();?>');
                                textbox.value = parseInt(textbox.value)+1;
                                event.preventDefault();
                                });
     $('#downImg_<?php echo $_product->getId();?>').live("click", function() {
                                  var textbox = document.getElementById('qty_<?php echo $_product->getId();?>');
                                  if (textbox.value>1)
                                  textbox.value = parseInt(textbox.value)-1;
                                  event.preventDefault();
                                  });
                                });
</script>
```

Answered in this thread [PHP generated textbox operation with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919013/php-generated-textbox-operation-with-javascript/924623#924623)

Thanks for viewing.

Comment: If you are using jQuery then why do var textbox = document.getElementById('qty_<?php echo $_product->getId();?> ? Just to $('#<?php echo $_product->getId();?>'); And textbox.value>1 then become textbox.val() > 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the # in the href - it has a defined behaviour and you need to override it, easiest way being to return false in your click handlers.

Edit: I *knew* this was a dupe - [preventDefault() on an  tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265478/preventdefault-on-an-a-tag)